When using `.position`, why is my SwiftUI View moving up when the parent frame becomes wider?
I'm trying to position a view within a specific frame in its parent view:
struct TestView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      // some backgroung
      Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.4)).scaledToFill()

      // control view that doesn't use .position. It's always centered
      Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

      // the view I'm trying to position
      Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .position(x: 60, y: 60)
    }
  }
}


I would expect the blue view to always be at the top left corner, offset by 10px.
This works when my frame is square:
#Preview {
  TestView()
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
}


but if I now make my frame wider, the view is moving up:
#Preview {
  TestView()
    .frame(width: 350, height: 300)
}


I'm really confused about why my view is not staying within 10px of the top left corner, and why it would move up when the frame is wider (if anything I would have expected a change in the X axis).

This is because of scaledToFill(). When you apply this to the gray Rectangle, the rectangle is first resized to its ideal size, which happens to be a 10x10pt square. This is then scaled to fill the available space.
When the window's width is greater than its height, the gray "square" will be scaled to exceed the window's height. Try adding .border(.red) to the ZStack - you will only see the red borders on the two sides, but not the top and bottom borders. This means that the origin of the ZStack is outside of the window, since the ZStack will resize itself to fit every view in it.
Here is a rather exaggerated diagram of what is happening:

The blue rectangle is the window, the red square is the Rectangle that is scaledToFill, and the dotted line outlines the blue Rectangle that has apparently "moved upwards".
Similarly, when the window's height is greater than its width, the square will be scaled to exceed the window's width. .border(.red) will now only show the top and bottom borders, but not the border on the sides.
You can set a different ideal size by, e.g. .frame(idealWidth: 100, idealHeight: 50), before scaledToFill. Now you can see that it is scaling a 100x50pt rectangle, and it only "works correctly" when the frame of the window has a W:H ratio of 2:1.
If you just want a rectangle that covers the whole window, you don't need scaledToFill() at all. Rectangles (all built-in Shapes in fact) will try to take up as much available space as possible.
